# What is the name for the part of piece of text which describes what a thing does?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the **specific name** used to describe the part of a piece of text which describes **what something does**?

**For example, from the following text:**

Space Exploration Technologies is a space-transportation startup company founded by Elon Musk. It designs, manufactures, and launches advanced rockets and spacecraft. develops crew and cargo capsules, engines, cryogenic tank structures, avionics, equipment, guidance, and control software. It is developing the partially reusable launch vehicles Falcon 1 and Falcon 9.

**What is the following part called?**

designs, manufactures, and launches advanced rockets and spacecraft

Comment: *Core*? *Crux*?

Comment: It's a *[compound] **verb***. We use nouns to identify what things ***are***, and verbs to say what they ***do***.

Comment: If a piece of writing contains a whole list of explanations of what various (parts of a tractor, say) do, do you want something describing the whole passage, or something describing each individual  'the cab protects the operator from ...' ... 'the gearboxes ensure that a useful range of torque ratings be available, for tough terrain or fast running on roads' ... 'the lights help when it is dark' ... ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking about the grammatical role of *designs, manufacturers, and launches advanced rockets and spacecraft*? (The part of a predicate that doesn't include a subject.) Are you asking about its meaning in the single sentence? Or are you asking about its role with respect to the entire paragraph?

Comment: A [**mission statement**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mission_statement) summarises the aims and objectives of a company, as in the question.

Comment: Along the lines of @WeatherVane's comment, I would call the text in question (and the text that follows it up to and including the word "software") a *purpose statement* or the *purpose* of the company, what it exists *to do*. https://www.lexico.com/definition/purpose: the reason for which something is done or created or for which something exists.

Answer (score 0):

> designs, manufactures, and launches advanced rockets and spacecraft

This part in your *passage* is called *the **heart** of the passage*. As you know *heart* of something means *the most important part of something* (*heart* is the most important organ in the body so we use it figuratively to mean *the most important or central part of something*).

*Designs, manufactures, and launches advanced rockets and spacecraft* describes the function/central idea of Space Exploration Technologies which is the most important part in the passage so you could say it's the *heart of the passage*.

Alternatively, you could say ***crux*** or ***core*** of the passage or simply ***function*** of the passage.

<sup>**Edit:** Replaced *text* with *passage*.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Does this refer to the part of a piece of text which describes **what a thing does**?

Comment: @DanielM, I think that's called *topic sentence* or perhaps *purpose*?

Comment: I would say that the heart of the text is **the first sentence** (*Space Exploration Technologies is a space-transportation startup company founded by Elon Musk*). Everything else could be removed, but the first sentence is essential to the passage. Do you mean that the phrase in question is the heart of the *sentence* instead?

Comment: @JasonBassford, I think yes. Because it conveys the main idea. Or it could be the *purpose* of the text.

Comment: I don't understand this response. Are you saying that the phrase is the heart of the **sentence** or the heart of the **passage**? In short, what are you referring to when you use the word *text*? (*Text*, to me, is ambiguous. Without qualification, when I see *text*, I almost always think of everything: the book, the chapter, etc. The entirety of what is actually presented. The phrase in question conveys the heart of the **sentence**, but not the heart of the **passage** …

Comment: @JasonBassford, Sorry. I meant the *heart of the passage*.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Can you add that clarification to your answer, so it's clear to everyone? :)

Comment: (*sigh*) Even though I appreciate the clarification, I strongly disagree with it. I think the phrase in question is definitely not the heart of the passage, but only of the sentence. The heart of the passage can only be the first sentence … (I would come up with my own answer, but I'm uncertain what the question is actually asking.)

Comment: @JasonBassford, Could it be [**mission statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_statement)? I can't get my head around it. :/